# GraphDB & GeoSPARQL

Tags: graphdb, geosparql

I run this query :

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
select *
where 
{
   ?x <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#hasGeometry> ?fGeom .
   ?fGeom geo:asWKT ?fWKT .
   FILTER (geof:sfWithin(
     '<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/27572> 
     Point (729326 2521619)   '^^geo:wktLiteral,
     ?fWKT))
}
```

against GraphDB with :

```
<http://data.edf.fr/departements/dep_france_dom/Geometry/2> a <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#Geometry> ;
<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#asWKT> "
<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/27572> MULTIPOLYGON (((729326 2521619,....
```

in the store and I don't get any result.
Do you think it is due to the 'french exotic' CRS?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

Here is the code :

```
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>

SELECT * WHERE {
    ?obj geo:hasGeometry ?fGeom .
    ?fGeom geo:asWKT ?fWKT .
    FILTER (geof:sfTouches(?fWKT, ''' POINT(729326 2521619)'''^^geo:wktLiteral))
}
```

Many things to say :

1. A `Point` that is on the border of a `Polygon` cannot be `Within` it. It `Touches` or `Instersects` the border instead.
2. In the interests of optimization, it is better that the variable geometry is the first argument in the function and the formal geometry the second by the way.
3. The big point is that `geof:` **needs** to work with `<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/OGC/1.3/CRS84>`. It is a big subject of many discussions but it is the only way that works... You then need to delete the CRS specification in all your geometries and requests. I have tried with different CRS and they didn't work neither.

As it is said in [this thread](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-locadd/2013Dec/0013.html).

Why precise the CRS in the WKT if it only works with WGS84? Why only WGS84 when it can be done easily by reprojection? I don't know and discussion is open.

Finally, again, be sure to correctly reproject your data.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I wrote  the arguments in the wrong order :) But even with the right one it doesn't give any result and it should. The '**' where supposed to bold the font ;)

Comment: As it is written in your DB, it is `<http://data.edf.fr/departements/dep_france_dom/Geometry/2>` (`Feature`) that has the `asWKT MultiPolygon ...`. It is an error since that the `asWKT` need to have a `Geometry` as a subject (`<http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#Geometry>` in your example).

Comment: So it is correct with `Feature -> Geometry -> WKT`. And you have `Feature -> (Geometry | WKT)`

Comment: here a simplified version of my DB :

Comment: here a simplified version of my DB and the associated query : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NrPC_w2-8zomMwrFyRTiPfWdkm9ji7Hb

Comment: I represented both the entities in QGIS and I'm sorry but the point is not in the Mutlipolygon ^^

Comment: Actually QGIS is a free and open-source cross-platform desktop geographic information system (GIS) application. It allows me to represent both the entities graphically.

Comment: I did the same thing with QGIS ... and for me it is. Maybe because I used the PostGIS version of my data and something went wrong  during the conversion ? I'll check and I tell you

Comment: The point proposed in the example and the point in your drive aren't the same. Indeed `Point (729326 2521619)` is part of the MULTIPOLYGON.

Comment: and graphDB doesn't give the right answer ... I'm a bit puzzled

Comment: Because the point is part of the boudaries, I tried this `FILTER (geof:sfIntersects(?fWKT,
            geof:buffer('<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/27572> POINT (729326 2521619)'^^geo:wktLiteral, 1.0, units:metre)
        ))`. But no result neither.

Comment: I transformed the MULTIPOLYGON in POLYGON, removing a level of parenthesis with the same result

Comment: The point is also in `<http://data.edf.fr/departements/dep_france_dom/Geometry/8>`. But I get it from `regex` and not topological reasoning.

Comment: I'm still stuck with the problem .